# jquery sortable() with two divs with overflow:auto; object disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want two divs with UL/LI lists where  I can drag&drop images from one to another. All works well, but when I have many objects I want one divs to get a scollbar and the other to automaticly grow. I achieve this by setting overflow:auto for both.

But the strange thing is that dragging with the UL itself works fine, but dragging it to the other UL makes the item get 'invisible'

If I remove to overflow:auto it works fine...

This is my js:

```
jQuery("#drag-kunst-in-lijst ul, #drag-kunst-alles ul" ).sortable( { 
    connectWith: '.sortable',
    delay: 100,
    scroll: false,
    cursor: 'move',
    start: function(event, ui){
        jQuery("#drag-kunst-alles").css("overflow", "hidden");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        jQuery("#drag-kunst-alles").css("overflow", "scroll");
    }
});
```

I've put a fidle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/edwins/zBTqX/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `appendTo` option. Default is that element is still in parent container while dragging. Using `appendTo` gives you ability to have it being dragged within a higher level parent. `body` usually works fine. While in `body` it will be visible regardless of posiiton relative to original parent

Note. Also set `helper` to `clone`. Will have to add some helper css and /or set helper class(s)also

**[See Sortable Docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-appendTo)**

Comment: Charlietfl & Matt,

Thanks a lot, you were both right! I've put a appendTo:'body' to the js code and set the position of both divs and ul's to 'static'. That did the trick.

Thanks! Edwin

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that your setting position relative for both divs and ul's.

You can try absolute or take out position all together.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/XE8mt/2/) based on yours i took out all positioning accept on the #drag-kunst-in-lijst div i set to absolute.

```
#drag-kunst-in-lijst {
        position:absolute;
        top:200px;
        width: 365px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

Comment: Charlietfl & Matt,

Thanks a lot, you were both right! I've put a appendTo:'body' to the js code and set the position of both divs and ul's to 'static'. That did the trick.

Thanks! Edwin